# Replace html text when it changes month to month

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar that changes month names , and its using an abbreviated Month name , aka Dec , Jan , Feb . I want to change that to full names. Is there a way to combine these functions into one ?

```
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER');
});
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Nov', 'NOVEMBER'); 
});
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('Dec', 'DECEMBER'); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain multiple `replace()` together

```
jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function(i, currHtml) {
  return currHtml
    .replace('Oct', 'OCTOBER')
    .replace('Nov', 'NOVEMBER')
    .replace('Dec', 'DECEMBER');
});
```

For all months, you can use an array with a replace loop:

```
const months = [
   /* add prior months */
   {short:'Oct', full:'OCTOBER'},
   {short:'Nov', full:'NOVEMBER'},
   {short:'Dec', full:'DECEMBER'}
];


jQuery('#calendar .month_header th').html(function(i, currHtml) {    
  months.forEach(function(e) {
    currHtml = currHtml.replace(e.short, e.full);
  });    
  return currHtml;
});
```